# Run a method on specific thread given the thread id

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

If i know a specific thread id. How to do the following?

Thread.**getThreadById**(id).continueWork();

Is it possible?

```
public class Test implements Runnable {

public void run() {
    while(true){
    pause();

    doSomework();
  }
}

private void doSomework() {
    System.out.println("do some work");
}

public synchronized void pause() {
    if (Tester.waitCondition == true) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void continueWork() {
    notify();
}
}

public class Tester {

public static boolean waitCondition = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread nThread = new Thread(new Test());
    nThread.start();
    waitCondition = false;
    Thread nThread1 = new Thread(new Test());
    nThread1.start();
    Thread nThread2 = new Thread(new Test());
    nThread2.start();
    Thread nThread3 = new Thread(new Test());
    nThread3.start();

    Long id = nThread.getId();
    Thread.getThreadById(id).continueWork();


}
}
```

Comment: No, not this way. You'll need to arrange for different `waitCondition`s, each thread with its own one.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I know it's not possible. But i want a way to do this

Comment: @AsiriLiyanaArachchi  Orz , they do , never used before ...

Comment: I just elaborated in my answer. Please take a refresher on `Object.wait` if you feel like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating:

```
public class Tester {
  // Apologies, I'm too lazy to create two separate files
  static public class Test implements Runnable {

    private void doSomework() {
      System.out.print(
          "do some work on Thread: "
         +Thread.currentThread().getId()
      );
      try {
        Thread.sleep(500); // just to simulate a load
      }
      catch(InterruptedException e) {
        // ignore
      }
    }

    public void run() {
      do {
        boolean shouldIWait=true;
        synchronized(Tester.lockingObj) {
          Boolean flag=Tester.waitConditions.get(Thread.currentThread().getId());
          if(null!=flag) {
            shouldIWait=flag.booleanValue();
          } // if null, the tester started me before creating my flag. I'll wait
          if(shouldIWait) {
            // I need to wait for someone to wake me
            try {
              Tester.lockingObj.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              // well, I'm interrupted, so I'll do no more work.
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        if(false==shouldIWait) {
          // waiting no more
          this.doSomework();
        }
      } while(true);
    }

  }

  public static Object lockingObj=new Object();

  public static TreeMap<Long, Boolean> waitConditions=
      new TreeMap<Long, Boolean>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread nThread = new Thread(new Test());
    Thread nThread1 = new Thread(new Test());
    Thread nThread2 = new Thread(new Test());
    Thread nThread3 = new Thread(new Test());

    // when starting, all threads will be waiting
    waitConditions.put(nThread.getId(), true);
    waitConditions.put(nThread.getId(), true);
    waitConditions.put(nThread.getId(), true);
    waitConditions.put(nThread.getId(), true);

    nThread2.start();
    nThread1.start();
    nThread.start();
    nThread3.start();

    Long id = nThread.getId();
    synchronized (lockingObj) {  // when notified, all thread should wakeup
      waitConditions.put(id, false);  // but only nThread will be allowed to doSomeWork
      lockingObj.notifyAll(); // wake up all the threads. 
                              // Those not allowed, will go into 
                              // back waiting
    }

    try {
      // just to have the main thread still running for a while
      Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    // maybe we want to switch of nThread and start another?
    synchronized (lockingObj) {
      waitConditions.put(id, true);
      waitConditions.put(nThread1.getId(), false);
      lockingObj.notifyAll();
    }
    try {
      // just to have the main thread still running for a while
      Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

  }  
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea. But when you mentioned " // when notified, nThread should start"  it actually doesn't start right?
it starts only after locking object's notify all

Comment: @AsiriLiyanaArachchi - it will briefly start, look into its entry in the waitingConditions and if not allowed to doSomeWork, it will go back into waiting.

Comment: What I understand from your logic is each thread is at waiting position at the start. And when you set waitingCondition to be false, it becomes  ready to  be looped with out any restrictions and once notified on lockingObject the thread on which we made waitCondition false will run continuesly. Other threads will also run one time and will get stuck in waiting condition again.

Comment: @AsiriLiyanaArachchi yeap, pretty much. Those for which you decide to switch-off the waiting and allow to do something (can be more than one) will doSomeWork in a cycle, at each cycle testing once if it's still allowed or should go back into waiting. Those which are not, will still listen to the one and only 'lockingObj' "beacon", will briefly wake up when notified-all and go back in waiting.

Comment: hmm this is not exactly what I want but this is useful. In my case threads are at running state almost all the time. I get to decide which thread to pause and again continue.

Comment: @AsiriLiyanaArachchi " I get to decide which thread to pause and again continue." well, fill your waitingConditions with false. Anyway, as [Thread.stop, suspend and resume are deprecated (and dangerous)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html), you don't have too many options outside a 'cooperation' between the controlling thread and the workers.

Answer (score 1):

You need block the thread with a lock , then call the lock's notify method to set blocked thread runnable .
If more than one thread to be continued , you will need `Condition` .
Like blow:

```
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

final Condition condition1 = lock.newCondition();
final Condition condition2 = lock.newCondition();

Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    try {
        lock.lock();
        condition1.await();
        System.out.println("end cdt1");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
    }
};

t.start();

Thread t1 = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    try {
        lock.lock();
        condition2.await();
        System.out.println("end cdt2");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }

    }
};
t1.start();

Thread.sleep(1000);

Thread tt = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
        lock.lock();
        condition1.signal();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
    }
};
tt.start();

Thread.sleep(2000);

Thread tt1 = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
        lock.lock();
        condition2.signal();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
    }
};
tt1.start();
```

Comment: as you can see there are more than one threads. If I pass lock object to a thread and if two threads are waiting how it'll know which thread should be continued and which should stay paused

Comment: @AsiriLiyanaArachchi  If so , you need use `Condition` .